# Write a python function to multiply integers to columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The below table having 1000 rows but here let's consider 3 rows:

| Date | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-24 | 12 | 1234 |
| 2021-02-01 | 13 | 6789 |
| 2020-04-30 | 14 | 4324 |

I want to write a python function where 2 is multiplied in column B, and 3 is multiplied in columns C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use loops, because possible vectorize multiple with dictionary:

```
d = {'B':2, 'C':3}
df[list(d.keys())] *= d
print (df)
         Date   B      C
0  2022-07-24  24   3702
1  2021-02-01  26  20367
2  2020-04-30  28  12972
```

If need function with argument DataFrame and dictionary use:

```
def f(data, di):
    data[list(di.keys())] *= di
    return data

d = {'B':2, 'C':3}
df = f(df, d)
print (df)
         Date   B      C
0  2022-07-24  24   3702
1  2021-02-01  26  20367
2  2020-04-30  28  12972
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. Can you tell me what's 'd' in the argument?

Comment: @Madness - It is dictionary.

Comment: What iis 'di' here?

Comment: @Madness - it is dictionary, I want distinguish with `d` use in `df = f(df, d)`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do `df[column] *= number`

```
values = {'B': 2, 'C': 3}
for k, v in values.items():
    df[k] *= v
print(df)
```

Or one liner

```
values = {'B': 2, 'C': 3}
df[list(values.keys())] *= values.values()
```

Output

```
         Date   B      C
0  2022-07-24  24   3702
1  2021-02-01  26  20367
2  2020-04-30  28  12972
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this might not be the best code but it will work

```
#data is the dataframe name     
for i in range(len(data)):
        data.loc[i,"b"] = 2*data.loc[i,"b"]
        data.loc[i,"c"] = 3*data.loc[i,"c"]
```